# Retrofit Rxjava error handler

Tags: error-handling, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a service class which is used to call api requset

here is an example method:

```
public Observable<List<Category>> test(Location location, int radius) {
    Observable<CategoryListResponse> observable = api.test();
    return observable
                .doOnNext(new Action1<CategoryListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(CategoryListResponse categoryListResponse) {
                        //handle error
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<CategoryListResponse, Observable<Category>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Category> call(CategoryListResponse categoryListResponse) {
                        return Observable.from(categoryListResponse.getCategories());
                    }
                })
                .map(new Func1<Category, Category>() {
                    @Override
                    public Category call(Category category) {
                        //do something...
                        return category;
                    }
                })
                .toList();
}
```

And subscribe() will be called in another class.

```
observable.subscribe(new Action1<List<Category>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Category> categories) {
                    //on success
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    //on error
                }
            });
```

I was thinking to do error handling in the doOnNext() before it is returned back. but how can I trigger onError()?

Comment: What do you mean error handling on the ``doOnNext()`` method? Retrofit already calls ``onError`` if the http code is not 2XX, or do you want some other error handling? As for the other question, you can simply trigger ``onError`` by throwing an exception in ``doOnNext`` AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw a runtime exception and control the exception in onError operator in case that happens

```
Observable<CategoryListResponse> observable = api.test();
return observable
        .doOnNext(list -> {
            try{
                request(list);
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }).onError(t->//Here you control your errors otherwise it will be passed to OnError callback in your subscriber)
        .flatMap(item -> Observable.from(item.getCategories()))
        .map(category-> category)
        .toList();
 }
```

Try to use lambdas, make your code much more clear and readable
You can see some RxJava examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive